# Send email to Facebook and get error POL-P8

Tags: facebook, email, smtp

I use SwiftMailer for send mail to facebook user. Sometimes I get response from facebook mail server 
said: 554 5.7.1 POL-P8 http://postmaster.facebook.com/response_codes?#pol-m Message refused (in reply to end of DATA command))

Please tell me what could be wrong?

Comment: Ask Facebook about meaning of `POL-P8 The message does not comply with Facebook's abuse policies and will not be accepted`. It is IMHO a very big rubber bag - expect little more than a guesswork here.

Comment: I have received a similar message, starting about 6 days ago, reacting to the url for my home page in my signature.  FB provides no links to explain any of their policies in any but the vaguest terms.

Comment: Do you get similar errors when sending to other domains?

Comment: I resolved problem)
\Swift_Preferences::getInstance()->setQPDotEscape(true);

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but this could be a result from a non-valid or non-existing SPF record for the domain name.

See more: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Policy_Framework